# Unable to disable CRC check on Cisco 2960-X

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, interface, ubiquiti, cisco-2960

I have a 48 port Cisco 2960-X running IOS Version 15.0(2)EX5.

I'm trying to connect it to a Ubiquiti EdgeRouter4 using a [Ubiquiti DAC Twinax cable.](https://store.ui.com/collections/unifi-accessories/products/unifi-sfp-dac-patch-cable).

I'm aware that this is technically not recommended, however:

It's for a homelab environment. I wouldn't do this for a production enterprise network, and I'm aware that Cisco do not recommend this, however - Cisco DACs are expensive.

When I plug the DAC in, I see the port come up in the logs, and them immediately go into an error state. Something to the effect of:

```
Jul  6 00:30:02.214: %GBIC_SECURITY_CRYPT-4-VN_DATA_CRC_ERROR: GBIC in port Gi1/0/50 has bad crc
Jul  6 00:30:02.218: %PM-4-ERR_DISABLE: gbic-invalid error detected on Gi1/0/50, putting Gi1/0/50 in err-disable state
```

I've tried running following [this guide](http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-switches/866-cisco-switches-3rd-party-sfp.html) which suggests running:

- `no errdisable detect cause gbic-invalid` followed by:
- `service unsupported-transceiver`

As well as running `service internal` which I found [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6948/non-cisco-sfps-defaulting-to-an-err-disable-state-in-2960s-and-2960-poe-switch).

to disable CRC checks and enable the use of third-party transceivers in the switch. However, I'm *still* getting CRC errors. It feels like there's something *else* I need to do to enable third party SFP transceivers.

Is there something I'm missing? Or something else I can try?

Comment: What's the exact model? (not all of them support SFP+) If you're seeing "bad crc" then there's something wrong with the module, or it's fundamentally incompatible with the switch. I've had this happen several times, the only fix is a different module. (and for the record, I've had HP switches refuse HP's own optics. The equation for signing them changed at some point.)

Comment: @Ricky The model is WS-C2960X-48TS-L. To save you the bother of looking it up, this one does not support SFP+, just SFP. However - I can't seem to find any reasonably priced SFP DACs, just SFP+. I was kinda hoping to bring the interface up, then hard set the port speed to 1G

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The giveaway is the port name ***Gi**1/0/50*. An SFP+ DAC generally requires an SFP+ (10G) port. There are very few SFP ports (1G) that accept SFP+ modules.

There are no SFP DACs, so you could use either a simple twisted-pair port (1000BASE-T), or SFP with multi-mode fiber (1000BASE-SX), or single-mode fiber (1000BASE-LX). If you do require 10G you'll need a 10G switch.

Comment: Ah, so you can't manually set it to do so, I take it...